# How many ways are there to put n figures on a chess board?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are the to place n chess figures on an n x n chess board in such a way that in each row (horizontal) there is at most 1 figure? 
note: the figures are indistinguishable from each other.

Comment: In how many ways have you tried to answer this question on your own?

Comment: $ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n^2 - i*n}{1}$ 
this is the approach that i have, although i am not sure wether it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each row of the $n$ rows must contain at most one of the $n$ figures then it has to contain exactly one figure.
(If one row would contain less, then a other row must contain more than one figure)

Then there are $n^n$ combinations, because you can multiply the number of combinations of each row $\begin{pmatrix}1\\n\end{pmatrix}\cdot\dots\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\n\end{pmatrix}=n^n$